# a loss that has proved durable and decisive

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "a loss that has proved durable and decisive" mean "the loss has been proved to be durable and decisive (a durable and decisive loss that has been proved)"?

> Mr. Barr’s comments came as another Trump ally signaled he was ready to move on after a surreal month of lawsuits, conspiracy theories and denials by the president of **a loss that has proved durable and decisive**.

> Source:  [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/live/2020/12/01/us/joe-biden-trump?referringSource=articleShare#barr-says-justice-dept-hasnt-uncovered-fraud-that-could-have-tipped-the-election-and-mcconnell-refers-to-new-administration)
> Justice Dept. Has No Evidence of Fraud That Would Undo Biden’s Win, Barr Says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trump's loss of the election has proved (turned out) to be durable (lasting) and decisive.